# How to execute mongo query with elemMatch from spring's mongo template?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

Data:

```
{ 
        "_id": ObjectId("54bb201aa3a0f26f885be2a3"), 
        "photo": "test",
        "likeCount": 2,
        "likes": [11, 10]
}
```

Mongo Query

```
db.photos.find(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("54bb201aa3a0f26f885be2a3"), 
    },
    { 
       "photo": 1
       "likeCount": 1,
       "likes": { 
          "$elemMatch": { "$eq": 11 }
       }
    }
)
```

Response From Query :-

```
{ 
        "_id": ObjectId("54bb201aa3a0f26f885be2a3"), 
        "photo": "test",
        "likeCount": 2,
        "likes": [11]
}
```

Spring boot Mongo template query I appended:-

```
query.fields().elemMatch("likes", new Criteria("likes").is(11));
```

which results to this likes=Document{{$elemMatch=Document{{likes=11}}}} so likes are not coming null in repsonse

Comment: are you using MongoRepository as well?

Comment: yes, I am using MongoRepository as well

Comment: so why dont you use `findByLikesIn(List<Integer> likesList)`

Comment: I am getting all the data with projection and elemMatch, my filter is "_id" not likes

Comment: is your document has a lot fields? I think you misunderstood the jpa query method. i say *find the document whose likes can have 11*

Comment: Hey as you see the above query it's finding everything by id and in likes field will only return me where I liked, 11 is my user id. for example there are 400 ids in likes field it will not return 400 it will only come back with 0 in case I haven't liked and 1 (11) where I have liked

Answer (score 3):

For future, if someone faces the same issue posting one way to use elemMatch on the array using mongo template in projection :

```
query.fields().elemMatch("likes", new Criteria("$eq").is(11));
```